# Combine Kotlin Unit flows without transform function

Tags: kotlin, reactive-programming, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow, kotlin-sharedflow

I have currently two SharedFlows that I need to combine to do something, but I don't really need the result from the transformation function, I only want to know if both "events" started yet. While implementing this I get this useless bracket body:

```
combine(
  flow1, // SharedFlow<Unit>
  flow2, // SharedFlow<Unit>
) { _, _ ->

  // Useless function body

}.onEach {
  // Do some work
}.launchIn(scope)
```

Is there a way I can do this more cleanly without the need for the transform function?

Comment: You can "Do some work" in "Useless function body" instead of `onEach`.

Comment: I think that might work, yeah. I'm going to try that out. Could you make this a response so I can mark as solved if it works correctly?

Answer (score 3):

You can "Do some work" in "Useless function body" instead of `onEach`:

```
combine(
  flow1, // SharedFlow<Unit>
  flow2, // SharedFlow<Unit>
) { _, _ ->

  // Do some work

}.launchIn(scope)
```